# Continuously bounding a matrix valued function by another matrix valued function

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, multivalued-functions

**Notation:**
The symbol $\mathbb{S}^{n \times n}$ denotes the set of symmetric matrices of order $n \times n$ and $A \succ 0$ denotes that $A$ is a positve definite matrix.

Let $M:S \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^{n\times n}$ and $N:S \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^{n\times n}$ be continuous symmetric matrix valued functions defined on a compact set $S \subset \mathbb{R}$.

If for each $s \in S$ there is an $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ (possibly dependent on s) such that 
$ M(s) \prec \alpha N(s)$
then there exists a continuous function $\bar{\alpha}:S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$ M(s) \prec \bar{\alpha}(s) N(s) \, ?$

I have tried to use [Michael selection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_selection_theorem) (which maybe is overkill) on the multivalued function 
$ S \rightrightarrows \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$ s \mapsto \{\alpha \in \mathbb{R} \mid  M(s) \prec \alpha N(s) \}$$
but I'm having difficulty in proving that this function is lower hemicontinuous...